# ForEach ADO loop variable mapping

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Running into a problem on a ForEach over a full result set from a query on an OLE DB connection. The parameter numbers in the execution results seem to be all screwed up. I would appreciate some more eyes on this as I am not seeing the problem.

Here is the query on the result of which I'm iterating:

[image]

[image]

Variable mapping in the ForEach Loop:

[image]

The variables:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the datatypes of the columns are in the table?

Comment: The SiteIDNumber is INT (signed 32 bit) and SequenceNumber is BIGINT (signed 64 bit)

Comment: I'm not sure why but it seems that DataTypes are not recognised correctly. What happens if you change the query to include a explicit cast to `INT` or `BIGINT`?

Comment: Changing the SSIS variables to 32bit makes it work. Changing the query to include an explicit cast to bigint has no effect.

Comment: Apparently there are some issues with conversion between BigInt and Int64 in past releases of SSIS not sure if they were fixed in the 2012 version. I think your best bet would be to store the bigInt as string.

Comment: Sounds like that'll work for me. Thanks for the solution! Can you post that as your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are some issues with conversion between BigInt and Int64 in past releases of SSIS not sure if they were fixed in the 2012 version. I think your best bet would be to store the bigInt as string.

Answer (score 0):

Use "select convert(varchar(20), BIGINTVARIABLE) from SOURCETABALE" instead of normal select. This will allow a workaround for the ForEach loop to work with the BIGINT variable.